# Slow FTP transfers over LAN compared to SMB

Tags: linux, ftp, raspberry-pi, samba, proftpd

I'm running an FTP server via ProFTPD on my RasberryPi 4 (4 GB RAM) as well as a Samba share folder to my Windows. I've got a sync setup from my PC to my pi HDD using Goodsync, and when I use my Samba share to sync it errors out when I'm transferring big video files (it got stuck on a 13 GB video file).

So that's another issue you may be able to help me with too! But anyway, so for the larger files to get synced over I have to change sync via the FTP. So, my transfer speeds over samba are great over my Gigabyte LAN reaching 90-120 MB/s, however over ftp it's maxing at about 20 MB/s. Any ideas why it would be going slower? Should I try using another FTP server on the pi other than PROFTPD? It's running explicitly TLS BTW. Or maybe should I use a SSH FTP server?
Cheers, 
Josh

EDIT: Same thing happens for NFS share on windows, it locks up with large file copies. For NFS/Samba it only locks up when copying to an external HDD (USB3), but not to the Pi SD

EDIT: I tried SFTP and it was slightly faster then FTPS (29MB/s) but still to slow. Any way I can speed up SFTP?

Comment: What TLS ciphers are you using for ProFTPd, and what is `smb encrypt` set to in smb.conf?

Comment: @grawity I don't have smb encrypt in my smb.config, so it would be at its default setting. As for the TLS ciphers, I'm not sure what that is, i didn't change any of the default settings for ProFTPd other then enabling TLS,

Answer (score 1):

FTP is a slow protocol that cannot use all the bandwith (IIRC the sender waits for an ACK from received before it send the next packet).

If you can set up an SSH link, copying via rsync can use all the bandwidth (unless you have an I/O bottleneck at either end).

Comment: No, you're confusing FTP with TFTP. The former uses a regular TCP stream with sliding window acks. The latter is UDP-based and has its own scheme with individual packet acks.

Comment: @grawity I worked for a TV channel and for their large transfers (a broadcast-grade video is easily 60GB) they used alternative methods because FTP was a huge waste of bandwidth.

Comment: @grawity ok, so I have ssh set up on my windows pc. Can i now use rsync to copy files over to my linux?

Comment: @xenoid Would you please give some reference about the reason why FTP wastes bandwidth? Not just something like "I have seen this before." To my opinion, 1) FTP works at applicatioin layer, it knows nothing about bandwith in lower layer. If you dont know something how do you even "waste" it? 2) If you means there is some design flaw in FTP, I really can't believe something like this exist for a protocol dedicated to file transfer and used by all the people for decades of years. I googled it and found nothing.

Comment: Because [there are workarounds](https://www.rapidseedbox.com/blog/slow-ftp-speeds#011). But if you want to use your all you bandwidth with a single connection, you need something else.